# Measurable functions(probability course)- proving a limit superior inequality for a sequence of functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

This is the problem:

Let $m(X)< \infty$, let $\lambda_n > 0, n\in \mathbb N$, and suppose $\{{f_n}\}$ is a sequence of extended real-valued measurable functions defined on $X$ that satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
 m\{|f_n|>\lambda_n\} < \infty$. Prove that $\lim \sup_n|f_n|/\lambda _n \leq1 $.

I am trying to understand a solution to this problem, which starts as follows:

Suppose $\overline{\lim}\frac{|f_{n}|}{\lambda_n}\geq 1$, therefore:
$ \exists A \subseteq X: \overline{\lim} \frac{|f_n|(x)}{\lambda_n} \geq 1, \forall x \in A$ such that  $  m(A)>0$ (I understand this part)

Let $B_n = \{|
f_n| > \lambda _n\}$ (As I understand this is the set of x's for which $|f_n(x)| > \lambda _n$ ? )

This is the part that I don't understand:

$A\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=j}^{\infty}B_n =:\underline\lim B_n $

$\Rightarrow m(B_n)\not \rightarrow$ $0$ (meaning $m(B_n)$ doesn't converge to 0)

$\Rightarrow \sum m(B_n) \rightarrow \infty $    and this is a contradiction because we know that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
 m\{|f_n|>\lambda_n\} < \infty$

The main statement that bugs me is why: $A\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=j}^{\infty}B_n =:\underline\lim B_n $.
Because that according to my knowledge, in general: $\lim\inf B_n\subseteq \lim\sup B_n$. So I don't see a reason for A to be a subset of $\underline\lim B_n$.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the first part: when you say that we assume that $\limsup_{\nu}\lambda_\nu^{-1}|f_\nu|(x) \geq 1$ do you mean that this holds pointwise for all $x$? If it holds for $x\in{}A$, why is $A$ required to be non-negligible? By the way, this problem is reminiscent of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis I'm not sure, I believe he said in class that it was by definition. Though this statement does make sense intuitive sense to me(This is a probability class and seems to not be too rigorous about measure theory, so I settle on it) He said it could be solved with the lemma, but we haven't studied it so he provided this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma). Consider the event

$$E_n = \{x{}:{} |f_n(x)| > \lambda_n \} =
\left\{
    x{}:{} \frac{|f_n(x)|}{\lambda_n} > 1
\right\}.$$

Since $\sum_n m(E_n) < \infty$, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma,

$$
m\left(\limsup_n E_n \right) = 0,
$$

that is, the probability that $E_n$ occurs infinitely often in $0$, therefore, $0 \leq \lambda_n^{-1}|f_n| \leq 1$ infinitely often, almost surely. As a result,

$$
\limsup_n \lambda_n^{-1}|f_n| \leq 1, \text{ a.s.}
$$